# Get sum/total from rangefilter

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am looking for a way to get the filtered sum of row 1. I found some solutions to get the sum from a datatable. But I would like to "draw" the total in an independant div, like others charts knowing that I am extracting data from a google sheet (See link bellow) :

https://jsfiddle.net/pvcb8gnw/4/

(For others, this Jsfiddle example extracts data from a Google spreadsheet, it has two filter ranges button/slider, has colored stroke and AreaChart for the main chart and the slider filter)

To make it work, I found this but couldn't make it work :

```
    var total = google.visualization.data.sum(data.getSortedRows(1).map(function(i) { return data.getValue(i,1); }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once the `'ready'` event fires on the dashboard,
you can get the filtered data table from the chart

```
chart.getDataTable()
```

it will be the same data table used to draw the dashboard, only filtered...

```
// get total for column 1
var total = google.visualization.data.sum(chart.getDataTable().getSortedRows(1).map(function(i) { return data.getValue(i,1); }));
```

Comment: I tried but I couldn't make it work... https://jsfiddle.net/pvcb8gnw/7/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was looking for a way to filter the number like the graph

Comment: So, when I filter the data (date range), the number will be changing

Comment: That's working great. Do you thinkm it can follow the filter from the three "buttons" at the top ?

Comment: Ok it'S working, I added settotal to each function. Moreoer there is something weird. In the example https://jsfiddle.net/ycmc6wh7/1/ When I filter the last two days for instance, the number is around 988, but the exact number the 692 (347 + 345)

Comment: i just realized where i had seen that sum formula, would recommend using as part of a group function and not use directly -- total fixed for two days --> [https://jsfiddle.net/ycmc6wh7/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/ycmc6wh7/3/)

Comment: Thank you ! It'S woking very well